# Ajax Call for load more button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to do load data with load more button. I have implemented like this in posts/index.html.erb:

```
  <div id="posts">
   <h1>Posts</h1>
    <%= render @posts %>
  </div>
  <div class="load-more-container">
   <%= link_to "Load More", posts_index_path, class: "load-more" %>
  </div>
```

Then _post.html.erb:

```
  <div class="post">
     <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
     <p><%= post.body %></p>
  </div>
```

Then index.js.erb:

```
  $('#posts').append('<%= escape_javascript render(@posts) %>');
```

In posts_controller I wrote like this:

```
@@count=2
def index
  if params[:id]
    @posts = Post.where('id < ?', params[:id])
  else
    @posts = Post.limit(@@count)
  end
  @@count+=2
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end
```

Then in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.load-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {
            $('.load-more').show();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting first 2 data:

```
Post1
Post2
load more
```

when clicking on load more I am getting like this:

```
Post1
Post2
Post1
Post2
Post3
Post4
```

but I want only:

```
Post1
Post2
Post3
Post4
```

Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the variable `@@count` is always equals `2`, on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fetching all records everytime click on **loadmore** button, Dont append result and overwrite with html

> $('#posts').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@posts) %>');

Comment: Thanks @krishnar . I got the output.

Comment: Hey @krishnar, I got one doubt whenever I am refreshing the page the value gets increased but I want to show 2 posts when I am refreshing the page. Load more button should not display as the data ends. Could you please help me getting this.

Comment: @SumitRanjan   @@count=0 unless request.xhr?      put this line in index action as firstline.

Comment: I have used like this @@count=2 request.xhr? and got that.

Comment: @SumitRanjan ok sorry. it should be 2

Comment: Hi krishnar, I want to hide my load more button once all the data will be displayed. How can I do that? I have tried like this:
 <% if @posts.count  %>
  <%= link_to "Load More", posts_index_path, class: "load-more" %>
<% end %> Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you replace 
`@posts = Post.limit(@@count)` => `@posts = Post.limit(2).offset(@@count - 2)`
 if you want load more 2 artices.